# Custom usage message for many-valued argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Given sth. like (or similar to):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("FILES", nargs="+", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now I'd like to have the many-valued positional argument `FILES` displayed in the usage message as

```
usage: cli.py [-h] FILES
```

instead of

```
usage: cli.py [-h] FILES [FILES ...]
```

Any step-by-step explanations or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Upvoted because I don't know how to do this, but my opinion is that the default usage message is clearer and better.

Comment: @Rocky Li: I don't disagree with your assessment ...but I know it can be done -- wasn't able to figure out the "how" by myself, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the built-in behavior of the default formatter: [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L587).

You could have your *custom formatter* with special handling for the `nargs="+"` type arguments:

```
import argparse


class CustomFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _format_args(self, action, default_metavar):
        get_metavar = self._metavar_formatter(action, default_metavar)
        if action.nargs == argparse.ONE_OR_MORE:
            return '%s' % get_metavar(1)
        else:
            return super(CustomFormatter, self)._format_args(action, default_metavar)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=CustomFormatter)
parser.add_argument("FILES", nargs="+", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Would print out:

```
usage: cli.py [-h] FILES
cli.py: error: the following arguments are required: FILES
```

Answer (score 1):

fbahr, I just decided to dive into the [source code of argparse](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py). I found out the formatting of the usage is hardcoded, [look at it here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L588). The only way you can override it is **inheriting from HelpFormatter** (the default class used when creating a new ArgumentParser instance) and say to the parser to use the class you created, to **use your own formatter**. You will have to **override** a "private" method (it is prefixed with an underscore) named *_format_args*, which is a little ugly and anti-pattern (in fact the only reason you can do that is because we are using Python) but it seems to be the only way to customize argparse the way you wanna do it.

```python
import argparse

class NArgsCustomUsageHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):

    def _format_args(self, action, default_metavar):
        get_metavar = self._metavar_formatter(action, default_metavar)

        if action.nargs == argparse.ONE_OR_MORE:
            result = '%s' % get_metavar(1)
        else:
            result = argparse.HelpFormatter._format_args(self, action, default_metavar)

        return result

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=NArgsCustomUsageHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument("FILES", nargs="+", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The code above just change the default behaviour if the action to be formatted needs at least one argument (`nargs='+'`), otherwise it doesn't do anything different.

[image: This is the output]

I hope this help you!

Comment: Modifying 'private' methods is how all the other `HelpFormatter` subclasses work.  In creating a subclass you are assuming the role of a developer with all its privileges and responsibilities (at least within your own programming domain).